# Unable to hide network activity indicator

Tags: ios, swift

I'm attempting to hide the network activity indicator using the code below. From everything I've gathered, this should be a rather easy task however I've been completely unsuccessful. I've tried implementing it in my app delegate and the view controller itself to no luck.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false;
```

Has anybody had this problem before? is there a solution?

EDIT:

Through some rigorous debugging I was able to find the source of the problem: Parse Analytics. Unfortunately they haven't yet allowed a feature to turn this off.

Comment: Please try searching "hide network activity indicator" and look at all the results: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hide+network+activity+indicator

Comment: Thanks Raurora. Have a look at my edit, I found the source of my problem.

Comment: Did you try to do it in main thread with dispatch_async dispatch_get_main_queue block?

Answer (score 1):

Parse enables the network activity indicator during queries, uploads, etc automatically.

You can disable the default behaviour using [PFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager.html#//api/name/enabled):

```
PFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager.sharedManager().enabled = false;
```

Comment: Also note, if you're using Parse, then you should use their activity indicator manager to keep track of your own pending requests too. Use `incrementActivityCount` when you start a request, and `decrementActivityCount` when it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid confusion about what service is using the internet by letting Parse do its thing (most likely you can do nothing about it) and indicate loading in your app via your own `UIActivityIndicatorView`.